# Ajax url different for Chrome?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I noticed that the following script does not work in Chrome but it works with all other browsers:

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'pages/add.php',
   data: $("#frm-upload").serialize(),
   dataType: "json",
   type: 'POST',
   ...
```

When using the url "pages/add.php", it won't work, I have to add / like "/pages/add.php".
In other browsers, I don't have this issue so I wonder why Chrome is struggling with this?

It's very difficult to find specific information about this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess it has to do with the fact that Chrome tries to hide the "http://" in the address bar. I had the same problem a while back, and just gave in and put the "/".

Comment: Ok thx, I never thought that a browser could have effect on ajax calls but now I do :)